# How to allow acceptance of first two layers of classes as types within this three-layer hiearchy?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I think I've overcomplicated my generics design in my app (am going to try to simplify it), but regardless I want to see if this is possible.

Let's say there are the following classes (this is design of my 3-layered hierarchy in my app):

```
abstract class A<T extends A<T>> // LAYER 1
abstract class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<T> // LAYER 2
class C extends B<C> // LAYER 3
```

**First layer (class A)** insures class B and C located in 2nd or 3rd layer extends class A with type itself (B and C, respectively).

**Second layer (class B)** insures class C located in 3rd layer extends class B with type C and extends class A with type C (thus inheriting from both).

**Third layer** satisfies contract of first two layers.

Now, I have another class that is the following:

```
class D<T extends A<T>>
```

I want to allow `T`to be either `A`, `B` or `C`. I've tried the following three:

```
new D<A<?>> or new D<A> // not allowed, A must extend A<A>
new D<B<?>> or new D<B> // not allowed, B must extend A<B> (it extends A<?>)
new D<C> // allowed
```

Is there are simple change I can make to my design to allow the first two to be allowed?

Here is an example of why I need this functionality:

```
List<? extends B<?>> list = ...; // a list containing subclasses of B
for (B<?> item : list) {
    D<B<?>> result = new D<B<?>>(item); // not allowed
}
```

Comment: Why not create a `class E extends A<E>` instead of trying to reference `A` recursively?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that `A` and `B` are `abstract`. `new A<...>(...)` never appears. However, the reason I want to accept them is because I have a list that has subclasses of `B`, and in the for-each loop I need to treat the objects in the loops as type `B` in order to iterate over them and create a instance of `D` for each of them. In addition, I don't need `C`-specific functionality, only `B` specific functionality..

Comment: Can you include an example in your question?

Comment: @shmosel I've included an example to illustrate the last part of my comment above.

Comment: I think the problem is that there's no guarantee every `B<?>` is compatible with `T extends A<T>`. For example, the list might contain a instance of `class F extends B<C>`, which is valid because Java can't enforce self types.

Comment: I added a solution that I think will work (atleast until I discover another flaw in the model). So I tested what you said, and it turns out I am able to do: `class C1 extends B<C1>` along with `class C2 extends B<C1 (NOT C2)>`, like you said. I thought that by making `B` declared like `class B<T extends B<T>>`, for any class named `X` the required declaration would be `class X extends B<X>`, and `class X extends B<(other class)>` wouldn't count. Do you have any more insight on why that isn't the case? Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem (surprisingly, simplifications were not the solution).

I had to change the **layer 2** class `B` from:

```
abstract class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<T> // LAYER 2
```

to

```
abstract class B<T extends A<T>> extends A<T> // LAYER 2
```

I don't actually know why that would solve the errors. What I did was rework my entire hierarchy from the ground up, thinking about every type limitation I put in place. Eventually, given the last comment on my question, I realized that the use of `B<T>` was providing no benefit over `A<T>`.

Comment: Wildcards shouldn't give you warnings. What exactly caused a warning?

Comment: @shmosel I saw your suggestion of keeping `A<T>` (don't know why you edited it out) and finally got it working while keeping the exact same warnings in place (effectively I fixed the error reverting this solution completely, only have warnings now). I have a method in `D` returned the parameter in the constructor of type `T` (so `D<? extends B<?>>#getType()` should return an instance of `B`). However, when that is done a warning `Unchecked method #getType() invocation` is shown. I will update the above answer with my new class declarations.